# cannot resolve the symbol R in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tied deleting these permission from Manifest file manually, and tried building the project, but unfortunately, every time these codes are getting generated after build project finish.
And in my codes it is showing an error "Symbol R cannot be recognised"

how can i make it working.?

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION "/>
```

Comment: i have cleaned it several time but its not working.  @Bidhan A

Comment: clean your project, Go to File->invalidate caches and restart->invalidate and restart.

Comment: Could you show us all your manifest to see if there is another error?

Comment: its working fine, I followed your suggestion , Thanx @AdiTiwari

Comment: Well then you can upvote my answer @Raul-9'1

Answer (score 0):

Try

Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

If this doesn't work check that you have the latest version of SDK.
Finally check all xml files too.

Answer (score 0):

If cleaning doesn not works that means you are using a older build tool version(Currently this is bug in studio). To fix this go to

```
1. File
2. Project Structure
3. Select your module(like app)
4. Inside the properties tab select latest build tool version
5. click Apply and then ok
6. Restart Android studio
```

Hope this will help