# Cannot resolve the symbol R

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Not a duplicate of [cannot resolve the symbol R in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071568/cannot-resolve-the-symbol-r-in-android-studio) and related questions to above.

I am trying to use the location services in my app. I am following the tutorials http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html and also the Google Android developer guide on how to setup Google apis.

After changing gradle and manifest, I encountered the error that the symbol R can not be resolved.
I added the following line to gradle app file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

and this line to manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I tried cleaning project,
restarting android studio
sync project with gradle 
re importing the packages
among others to be tried

I am not sure why is this appearing and how to fix it?
EDIT 1
After commenting out the

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

The R is now not in red color but it doesnto recognize the GoogleAPiClient any more..

EDIT 2
changed the statement above to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.+
```

resolved the issue thought not a good approach

Comment: You are probably importing the wrong R file in your Activity.

Comment: it doesnt show the alt+enter tip to import it all it says it cannot resolve.how do i import it manually

Comment: import com.yourapplication.id.R;
replace com.yourapplication.id with your applicationId which you can find in your gradle. Don't forget to delete the current imported R file.

Comment: You could always import the project to android studio, as if it was an old one. might clean some stuff.

Comment: Com.package name wala import kiya kya bhai?

Comment: that didnt solve the problem

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan where exactly you added meta tag in Manifest?

Comment: @nikhil in the application tag,

Comment: @ShahenshaKhan I have tried with same process as you have mentioned in question. I didn't get any error and application run successfully. Please check in your layout XMLs and drawables if you have done something wrong there

Comment: i added some edit to question, abjectly request to check please

Answer (score 2):

There may be some errors in some of your program files like java or xml. Due to that you are getting **the symbol R can not be resolved**.

**Suggestion:** Please double check the gradle and build it once for getting the actual error in your project and also use **ctrl + shift + o** to remove unused imports with use of shortcut settings like eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just Click on Build -> Rebuild Project option in your Android Studio.

Comment: this issue was caused because the errors in your XML files. Once you fix the XML errors, do a clean/build, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean and rebuild your project and check the import for R also it should be your package_name.R

Answer (score 0):

changed the statement above to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.+
```

resolved the issue but it is not a good approach